# generating random strings and matching them in python

Tags: python-3.x, random

this is a python program to generate a random string and to match it with a user given output and to get a return on the amount of attempts by the computer but i cant get the try count
 import random

class txt:

```
  def __init__(self):
        self.txt = None
        trycount = 0

  def maketxt(self,txt):
        txt = ""
        a = []
        a.append(txt.split())
       # return a

#  def match(self):
        tokenlist = ["a", "b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
        matchlist =[]
        while (len(matchlist) <=24):
              x =random.choice(tokenlist)
              matchlist.append(x)
        if matchlist == a:
              print(trycount)
        else :

              trycount += 1
              match()
```

t = txt()
t.maketxt("hagjkrshgujrahg")
I keep getting the error
File "C:/Users/#####/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/test1.py", line 25, in maketxt
    trycount += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'trycount' referenced before assignment

Comment: use self.trycount instead of trycount

Comment: hi btw thanks 4 ur help I currently did get the code into working condition but have a problem in  the l9imited number of recursions that python allows is there a way to get access to a higher number of recursion depth

Comment: use import sys, and then sys.setrecursionlimit(depth). However, be cautious while doing it.